# Tool bar below table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need some clever hints here :)

I need to add a tool bar to my page containing a table view. If the table does not fill up the entire page I need the tool bar to be positioned at the bottom at the page but if the table is longer than the page I need the tool bar to be positioned at the end of the table.

What to do?! :/

Thanks a lot for any help,
Stine

Answer (score 1):

Use the footer view of UITableViewDelegate....

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Simply return a view from this and it will be placed at the bottom of the specified section (either a single section or your last one).

Also use..

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

To tell the Table view the height of the view.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :) I have added a view to the table footer which contains my tool bar at the bottom and then I return `MAX(44, suggestionsTable.bounds.size.height - ([self.suggestions count] * 44));` in `the heightForFooterSection`... I do not like the hard coded 44 though! Is there a better way? :D

Comment: If 44 is the height of the footer view then you can instantiate the class in viewDidLoad and then use... myFooterView.frame.size.height;

Comment: But what about the height of the cells in the table? :)

Comment: ahhh I see, well if they are all the same then it is fine, I tend to put a #define kCellHeight 44 at the top of my classes for instance.

Comment: Well, my `heightForFooterSection` prevents the table from bouncing back into its right place when its dragged up... don't know if that made any sense!! ;)